# If each student ID number either begins with $4$ digits or ends with $3$ upper case letters, the total number of student ID numbers is

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**My problem is at letter D Below**

Suppose that student ID numbers consist of strings of 11 characters where the allowed characters are upper case letters and digits.

a) If each student ID number starts with 4 digits, the total number of student ID numbers is

Answer: $10^4 \cdot 36^7$

> There are $10$ digits that we can choose from and $4$ places for them to fill so we have $10^4$. Then there are still $7$ places to be filled with either a uppercase letter or a number. So I combine the alphabet which has $26$ letters with $10$ (the number of digits that you can choose from) to get $36$ and then bring it to the power of the $7$ (the number of places left to be filled by either a number or letter) which is $36^7$.  To get the total, I multiply to get my answer above.

b) If each student ID number ends with $3$ upper case letters, the total number of student ID numbers is

Answer: $36^8 \cdot 26^3$

> There are $8$ slots to be filled with either a letter or number so I have $36^8$. There are three slots in which hold only a letter so I have $26^3$. I multiply them together to get the answer above.

c) If each student ID number both begins with $4$ digits and ends with $3$ upper case letters, the total number of student ID numbers is
Answer: $10^4 \cdot 36^4 \cdot 26^3$

> There are $4$ places to be filled with digits, so it's $10^4$. There are three places to be filled with letters at the end, so it's $26^3$. There are $4$ places left that either have letters or numbers so that is $36^4$. I multiply values as shown above.

d) If each student ID number either begins with $4$ digits or ends with $3$ upper case letters, the total number of student ID numbers is

> I thought that adding a and b together $$(36^8 \cdot 26^3)+(10^4 \cdot 36^7)$$ would work but it didn't turn out the way I expected. So what exactly is the right way to do it?

Comment: adding both of them includes some extra counting; consider part (a), 7777XYZ8AAA is valid for (a) BUT also for (b), hence counting it twice

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that d) asks for ID numbers **either** beginning with 4 digits **or** ending with 3 upper case letters. If we add a) and b) up to get the answer, then IDs beginning with 4 digits **and** ending with 3 upper case letters will be added up twice. Therefore we need to delete that part, *i.e.*, the answer is a)+b)-c).